# Sonata-Project's Google Authenticator: Undefined Method "getTwoStepVerificationCode" from Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User

Tags: sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-sonata, symfony-2.8, sonata-user-bundle

guys!

I am currently working on a project built on Symfony 2.8 and a few Sonata-Project bundles. The goal is to achieve Two-Factor Authentication (a.k.a Two-Step Verification). I saw that Sonata-Project has a package for implementing such functionality and installed it. Then configured the `app/config/config.yml` file according to [sonata's documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-x/doc/reference/two_step_validation.html), but when I try to log into my Dashboard from the login form, I do that without any further obstacles (no 2-Factor Authentication Prompt). Here, on stackoverflow.com, I've seen a few answers, (not-fully) related to my question, that suggest running `php app/console sonata:user:two-step-verification *ADMIN_USER_NAME*`. I've tried to run this command in my terminal, but got this exception thrown:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedMethodException]
Attempted to call an undefined method named "getTwoStepVerificationCode" of class 
"Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User".
```

What seems to be the problem here? Why such method doesn't exist? How can I resolve this issue?

P.S.: I try to use this Google-Authenticator package in conjunction with Soanata-Project's UserBundle as [it is "a feature" (if I may call it such) of the latter](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-x/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Does your application properly extend `Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser`? Because if not you will have this issue. Check your class `Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User`.

Comment: `Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User` does lack `getTwoStepVerificationCode` method. How can I set it up and how can I edit the entity, so such column (TwoStepVerificationCode) to exist in my `Users` table in DB?

Comment: @EmilAvramov your User entity must extend ```Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser``` for TwoStepAuthentication to work.